# Listing Kafka clusters and brokers

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I try to develop a **Kafka GUI** on Django. I can list **topics** of brokers, **partitions** and **clients** using kafka-python.

Is a programmatic way to retrieve list of clusters and brokers?

I can save **clusters** and **related brokers** as database tables as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ClusterMetata.brokers()`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/ClusterMetadata.html)

You can only connect to one cluster at a time, so you need some other solution to find all Kafka clusters.

Alternatively, there's plenty of existing Kafka GUIs, most of which are built on JVM languages, however.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I will only publish for practicing Django and Kafka in the same project.